# why httpbin.org as adding with API URL on POST OR request i am using angular cli proxy conf for calling API

Tags: angular, post, proxy, request

We have setup proxy configuration for API calling at our local environment,

```
{
   "/api/*": {
   "target": "https://172.16.2.10",
   "secure": false,
   "pathRewrite": {
   "^/api/*": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

And then calling POST API using angular http service,

```
this.http.post('/api/slots/1/apps/app-nat/flows?api_version=1', data).map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

when calling API through browser then httpbin.org is adding instead of localhost:4200 with our base URL(api call url), just like this,
In browser:
http://httpbin.org/api/slots/1/apps/app-nat/flows?api_version=1   // Sending OPTIONS request.

Note: this issues is only with POST or DELETE request, GET request is working fine using proxy conf.

Our GET API request examples(Its working):

In code:

```
 this.http.get('/api/slots/1/apps/app-nat/groups?api_version=1').map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

In Browser:
http://localhost:4200/api/slots/1/apps/app-nat/flows?api_version=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issues, actually i have added httpbin.org in environment.ts file in apiURL that's why it's showing issues, i have removed it and add localhost:4200 in apiUrl now it's working fine.